# The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: 16.04, tls

I'm a beginner ubuntu user, and probably removed something I should have not to.
Now when I want to open in either Chrome, Chromium or Firefox some web pages:

1. I cannot upload photos/any file, the page is running but nothing happens;
2. Sometimes the page just says, "connection failed',
3. some pages do not even load...

With a friend we tried to localize the problem, used the `curl` in Terminal and the following message we got, after several tryings as well:

```
$ curl
https://secure-web.cisco.com/1UjZvaFXylKMUS8eSdCfbbKAk1o8eOwyUbZWinGVDbO4PZJi_lCx_9W6A5aCGm7Y7TRyMZ9_2YzAGA9SkPEyJuqBo34wXEZWLbqh8nXHPIommnz_s1Iw2seS9DjGgyTDpIIy3NAusf6W7DKPkLqvsPQFn2Av26cx0AdfmOFNpkSJkTxCFk0airlZWOZBBFUE-S3dsLqHkm68A_7iq3BwPp6pp95WKQuTu5diERcS-apjarsnggk-Gq3IM4TTJI1Cgu43o8VPFqAi180o8sqS-c7xgALeBIJUg0YIeaj8qoz0zyhBIaIm7PbichXA0mp1pyCT2ELfMPQob1EihfFDMQkF_bl8NLkAzFmL9WLYH6JVYHYiuhkVrQ8NA08fgZ7ukcwJF_MGZufAoEVyWox1RW0jzMyCE7Xac7xWWY_Jt9DAdtUXNYKY3WhOeN9w9pLM2vY1fMkXoTly_9LigF5e9OQ/https%3A%2F%2Fget.adobe.com%2Fflashplayer%2F
*   Trying 193.104.215.66...
* Connected to get.adobe.com (193.104.215.66) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 704 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* server certificate verification OK
* server certificate status verification SKIPPED
* common name: get.adobe.com (matched)
* server certificate expiration date OK
* server certificate activation date OK
* certificate public key: RSA
* certificate version: #3
* subject: C=US,ST=California,L=San Jose,O=Adobe Systems Incorporated,CN=get.adobe.com
* start date: Fri, 23 Sep 2016 00:00:00 GMT
* expire date: Fri, 27 Sep 2019 12:00:00 GMT
* issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
* compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol

> GET /flashplayer/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: get.adobe.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Date: Sun, 11 Jun 2017 15:35:48 GMT
< Server: JRun Web Server
< location: /flashplayer/otherversions/
< Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Set-Cookie: SETTINGS.LOCALE=en%5Fus; HttpOnly;domain=.adobe.com;expires=Tue, 04-Jun-2047 14:35:48 GMT;path=/cfusion/
< Connection: close
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< 
* GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

Probably the problem is with the TLS connection, but we could not figure out what exactly and how to fix. I upgraded my 15.10 Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS. This did not solve the problem, but rather deepened it (problems with more web pages).

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in `GnuTLS` and `curl` was compiled using it instead of `OpenSSL`. You should try using a version compiled with `openssl`.

Comment: But how to make that version, could you please provide step-by-step instructions?